# Order States aphabetically in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop-1.7

Does anyone know how can you order alphabetically states when you are editing o creating a new customer address.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it by overriding the file State.php

Just create a new file inside /overrides/classes/State.php and paste this code:

```
<?php class State extends StateCore {
/**
 * Get states by Country ID.
 *
 * @param int $idCountry Country ID
 * @param bool $active true if the state must be active
 *
 * @return array|false|mysqli_result|PDOStatement|resource|null
 */

    public static function getStatesByIdCountry($idCountry, $active = false)
    {
        if (empty($idCountry)) {
            die(Tools::displayError());
        }
        return Db::getInstance()->executeS(
            'SELECT *
            FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'state` s
            WHERE s.`id_country` = ' . (int) $idCountry . ($active ? ' AND s.active = 1' : '') . '
            ORDER BY `name` ASC'
        );
    }
}
```

It just adds **ORDER BY `name` ASC'** to the SQL query, then it gets the states ordered alphabetically.

Best regards